# SQLite Read Column

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a SQlite Database with an `id,name,number`.

My problem is that I need a command which gives me the name connected with an `AutoComplete` function in an `editView` and in another `editView` there should stand the correct number related to the name. For example: I have the name rice and the number `50`. I want the rice in the first `editText` and connected to the `AutoComplete` and the number `50` in another `editText`.

I am looking up the internet and also some manuals for SQLite for that, but it seems like I am too blind to find the right command. Someone has a suggestion for a tutorial where this is shown or someone has the right command for me to read this information out of my database.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT number FROM table_id_name_number WHERE name = 'rice';
```